# Window.open in an iframe idea

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure if this can be done. I have this code in my view:

```
  <div class="col3">
    <a id="training-launch-button" href='javascript:OpenScormModuleWindow(<%: Model.ScormModuleId %> , "<%: ViewBag.ScormModuleUrl %>", "<%:  ViewBag.title %>", <%:  ViewBag.WindowWidth %>, <%:  ViewBag.WindowHeight %>);' class="button" onclick ="Test()">Launch</a>
  </div>

 function OpenScormModuleWindow(scormModuleId, scormModuleUrl, title, width, height) {
   _scormModuleId = scormModuleId;
   InitializeUserScormModule();
   scormModuleWindow = window.open(scormModuleUrl, "title", "width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", resizable = 1");
   scormModuleWindow.focus();
}
```

when i hit launch it calls:

```
  function Test() {
      alert("try launch in new window");
      var newwindow = document.getElementsByClassName('targetblank');
      newwindow.target = '_blank';
      document.getElementById("iframe").src = "<%: ViewBag.ScormModuleUrl %>";
      document.getElementById("iframe").addEventListener('resize', function () {
          setWindowSize();
      });
  }

  function setWindowSize() {
      alert("in set winodw size");
      var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
      if (typeof (window.outerWidth) == 'number')
      {
          myWidth = window.outerWidth;
          myHeight = window.outerHeight;
          alert(window.innerWidth + "  1  " + window.innerHeight + "  " + document.documentElement.clientWidth + "  " + document.documentElement.clientHeight);
          alert(myHeight + "   " + myWidth);
          $("#LaunchWidth").val(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
          $("#LaunchHeight").val(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
          updateSaveButtons();
      }
```

then i have in my view the iframe:

```
  <iframe id="iframe" class="targetblank"></iframe>
```

it also never gets to the alert in setWindowSize :(
the line `document.getElementById("iframe").addEventListener('resize', function ()` is not working.

Comment: If you wanted to open the url in an frame, you'd just create or get an iframe, then set the src of the iframe to the URL you're passing to window.open.

Comment: please see OP..I have that now but not sure if it is correct, thanks

Comment: I guess I'm not sure of your goal. Do you want to open a url in a resizable window? Do you want an event to fire when the window is resized? Why do you need it in an iframe? I think you need to add a lot more context, and possibly a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you're trying to accomplish.